# MathML not rendering/reading/responding

Tags: jquery, formatting, mathjax, mathml

At first I'd like to share with you the line, which I consider properly formatted for MathML:

`[ [ 33, -13, -19 ], [ -9.75, 22.75, -12 ], [ -23.75, -20, 44.75 ] ]` 
There are two backticks in case stackoverflow renders them so that you not to be able to see them... 1 is before the first [ and one after the last, closing ].

Another important thing is that I need to update this expression dynamically. I mean - not onload() but after and relatively frequently (more than once and so on...). I just suppose that there is a load-time connection between the render of MathML and the page load at all, I suppose that the page loading triggers the the math thing's parser... 
So, if the formatting is ok, I'd like to know what may be wrong. I'm open to any suggestions. :D

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: <div id="matrixRes2"  class='matrices'> ` [</div>
I form the expression through a for loop. However, it actually doesn't matter because MathML is mostly interested in the final result then in the way of reaching it... should be.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Authoring

Comment: Ok, now I'll read it but I'd like to just mention something. I tried to get the result - the expression which I posted on the main post above - and to put it in a div. So at this stage I have a div in which the for loop compounds the expression and another div holding directly the expression without any pre- calcs, loops etc. The result is - the first div does not render through MathML, the second gets properly formatted! This proves my initial theory about the onload triggering of the render... @guest271314 I'll check now the what you've proposed. :)

Answer (score 0):

> At first I'd like to share with you the line, which I consider properly formatted for MathML:
>
> ```
> [ [ 33, -13, -19 ], [ -9.75, 22.75, -12 ], [ -23.75, -20, 44.75 ] ]
> ```

This line isn't MathML. If you are trying to represent a matrix, the MathML code is

```
<math display="inline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mtable><mtr><mtd columnalign="center"><mn>33</mn></mtd><mtd columnalign="center"><mo>−</mo><mn>13</mn></mtd><mtd columnalign="center"><mo>−</mo><mn>19</mn></mtd></mtr><mtr><mtd columnalign="center"><mo>−</mo><mn>9.75</mn></mtd><mtd columnalign="center"><mn>22.75</mn></mtd><mtd columnalign="center"><mo>−</mo><mn>12</mn></mtd></mtr><mtr><mtd columnalign="center"><mo>−</mo><mn>23.75</mn></mtd><mtd columnalign="center"><mo>−</mo><mn>20</mn></mtd><mtd columnalign="center"><mn>44.75</mn></mtd></mtr></mtable></math></p>
```

and the LaTeX code that MathJax need it

```
\begin{matrix}
  33 & -13 & -19 \\
  -9.75 & 22.75 & -12 \\
  -23.75 & -20 & 44.75
\end{matrix}
```

If you want to get render the line you typed at the question, the MathML code is

```
<math display="inline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mo stretchy="false" form="prefix">[</mo><mo stretchy="false" form="prefix">[</mo><mn>33</mn><mo>,</mo><mo>−</mo><mn>13</mn><mo>,</mo><mo>−</mo><mn>19</mn><mo stretchy="false" form="postfix">]</mo><mo>,</mo><mo stretchy="false" form="prefix">[</mo><mo>−</mo><mn>9.75</mn><mo>,</mo><mn>22.75</mn><mo>,</mo><mo>−</mo><mn>12</mn><mo stretchy="false" form="postfix">]</mo><mo>,</mo><mo stretchy="false" form="prefix">[</mo><mo>−</mo><mn>23.75</mn><mo>,</mo><mo>−</mo><mn>20</mn><mo>,</mo><mn>44.75</mn><mo stretchy="false" form="postfix">]</mo><mo stretchy="false" form="postfix">]</mo></mrow></math></p>
```

> I just suppose that there is a load-time connection between the render of MathML and the page load at all.

This doesn't make any sense in the scenario of native MathML support.

> I suppose that the page loading triggers the the math thing's parser...

If you are using MathJax their Javascript will trigger the parser after the page load. If you want to dynamic change something please read http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html.